# Regex htaccess remove multiple URL segments

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I had a Wordpress blog where the individual post URLs were set up like this:
http://blogname.com/knowledge-communities/2013/01/blog-title

I recently refreshed the site and they are now set to this:
http://blogname.com/blog-title

So if a user finds a link to an old blog post(through Twitter or other social media), I want to redirect them to the new URL structure by removing the 'knowledge-communities' segment and the date segments(2013/01).

I have this so far which is removing the 'knowledge-communities' segment, but I can't find a way to remove the date segments- /2013/01.
`RewriteRule ^knowledge\-communities/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex to catch the item after two groups of digits :

```
RewriteRule ^knowledge\-communities/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /\d{4}/\d{2}
```

will pick out your date string